# can we have cron schedule inside on:push block in github actions?

Tags: github, github-actions, devops, cicd, gitops

something like this  :

i want to trigger it only on Saturday if any Push happens on Master branch

```
 on:
      push:
        branches:
          - 'master'
        schedule:
          - cron: '0 0 * * SAT'
```

Answer (score 0):

`on:push` currently only receives `path`, `branch` and `tag` (include corresponding `-ignore` version).

See [Workflow syntax for GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushbranchestagsbranches-ignoretags-ignore)

There are other alternative (but not perfect) approaches:

1. Add a step to perform datetime calculation (use `bash` or other tools), and use `if:` condition the following steps.

   ```yaml
   on:
     push:
       branches: [master]

   name: some-name
   jobs:
     example:
       name: Example
       runs-on: ubuntu-latest
       steps:
         - name: Calculate date
           id: date
           run: |
             echo "cond=$($(date +'%w') - 6)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
         - name: Other steps
           if: fromJSON(steps.date.outputs.cond) == 0
           # Do something else
           # ...
   ```

   However, such calculation could be hard to implement when the cron expression is too complex.
2. Create a new workflow and use the cron trigger to periodically enable-disable workflow using GitHub cli. But notice that GitHub Actions do have random time delay (~several minutes) for cron triggers. See [Disabling and enabling a workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/disabling-and-enabling-a-workflow?tool=cli) for more info.